# Error installing Rmpi package on windows

Tags: r, package, mpi

I'm trying to install Rmpi package in R on windows8. the R version is 3.4.3 .

I got this message

```
 install.packages("C:/Users/Mariya/Desktop/Rmpi_0.6-6.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")package ‘Rmpi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

when I wanted to run this library I got this message :
The procedure entry point MPI_COMM_SPLIT_TYPE could not be located in the dynamic link library
c: user/.../R/win-library/3.4/Rmpi/libs/X64/Rmpi.dll

and when I click ok, I got this error in cosole:

```
library(Rmpi)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rmpi’:.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rmpi', details:call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Mariya/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rmpi/libs/x64/Rmpi.dll'/LoadLibrary failure: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I had ms-mpi in my computer, I removed it and installed MPICH2 that is told here http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/yu/Rmpi/windows2.htm

and then install Rmpi, but I got error again.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are installing from a downloaded zip instead of on-the-fly with `install.packages("Rmpi")`?

Comment: No, but now I test this way you suggested but the error continue.

Comment: I think your firewall rules prevent the complete download. In particular, it's preventing any .dll files to be downloaded

Comment: I turned it off and again installed the package but there was no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I send an email to the writer package Dr Hao Yu and found the solution.
I remove the MpiCH2 ,install msmpi and follow these Instructions : http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/yu/Rmpi/